# How to do generalization?

Tags: haskell

Earlier, it used to have `map` and `sequence` with following implementation:

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]

sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

then haskell contributors did generalize to:

```
traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b) 

sequenceA :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

Why they choose applicative over monad?

How they become the idea to generalize `mapM` and `sequence`? I want to understand the process, when I have to be more abstract. As you can see, functions `mapM` and `sequence` work only on list, but `traverse` and `sequenceA` are more abstract and work with all datatype that has `Traversable` implemented.

Comment: Every monad *is also* an applicative, so choosing applicative lets you use it for more things.

Comment: Don't worry too much about failing to generalize as much as possible. Often the fully general abstraction is so far away from concrete applications that gets little use in practice, since it becomes easier to reinvent the wheel than to exploit the abstract higher-kinded coinductive rotary device transformer combinator library. Finding the right level of abstraction requires a lot of effort and skills. (And, at least for theoretical purposes, it's very nice to read and understand super-abstract category-theoretic approaches to regular tasks -- many love Haskell just for that!)

Answer (score 2):

Applicative chosen because we want to chain actions but action order does not depend on previous results.

Monad: `action1 >>= \resultOfAction1 -> if P(resultOfAction1) then action1 else action2` (action chain may vary depending on results)

Applicative: `processCombinedResult <$> action1 <*> action2 <*> action3` (action chain fixed)

When traversing Traversable action order dictated by Traversable's internal structure and does not depend on each other results. Monad also can be used, but it more restrictive and it's ability to chain actions "dynamically" depending on results of previous actions is not required to implement these functions. So Applicative is chosen as less restrictive class which provides required functionality.